Verifying a type-punning, multibyte optimization
I am trying to verify a modified version of musl libc memchr which uses a type-punned optimization: it looks for the value in the prefix of the buffer until it is aligned on sizeof(size_t), then uses bitwise operations to advance by sizeof(size_t) bytes, and finally checks the buffer suffix one character at a time.
Safety properties don't seem to be a problem when using the Typed+cast model, but I am having trouble with correctness.
Here is the loop in question (I'll put the complete file below):
  // Advance i by sizeof(size_t).
  if (SS <= n && i <= (n - SS) && *(src + i) != c) {
    size_t pat = ONES * c;
    /*@
      @ loop assigns i;
      // @ loop invariant \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> *(src + j) != c;
      @ loop variant n - i;
     */
    while (i <= n - SS && !HASZERO(*((size_t *) (src + i)) ^ pat)) {
      i += SS;
    }
    //@ admit \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> *(src + j) != c;
  }

SS is the sizeof(size_t), ONES is a size_t where every byte has the value 1, and HASZERO compares the pattern to the buffer SS bytes at a time.
The admit annotation is a replacement for the commented-out loop invariant assertion that I really want to prove. These are the definitions of those macros:
#define SS (sizeof(size_t))
#define ALIGN (sizeof(size_t)-1)
#define ONES ((size_t)-1/UCHAR_MAX)
#define HIGHS (ONES * (UCHAR_MAX/2+1))
#define HASZERO(x) ((x)-ONES & ~(x) & HIGHS)

Are there any suggestions how to go about proving the loop invariant?
The command I'm using is frama-c -no-frama-c-stdlib -wp -wp-rte -wp-model=Typed+cast  mymemchr.c.
Here is the whole file:
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define SS (sizeof(size_t))
#define ALIGN (sizeof(size_t)-1)
#define ONES ((size_t)-1/UCHAR_MAX)
#define HIGHS (ONES * (UCHAR_MAX/2+1))
#define HASZERO(x) ((x)-ONES & ~(x) & HIGHS)

/*@
  @ requires s_valid: \valid_read(((const char *)s) + (0 .. n-1));
  @ ensures \result == 0 ||
     ((const char *)s) <= ((const char *)\result) < ((const char *)s) + n;
  @ assigns \result \from s, c, n;
 
  @ behavior not_found:
     assumes \forall integer i; 0 <= i < n ==> *(((const char *)s) + i) != ((unsigned char)c);
     ensures not_found_zero: \result == 0;
  
  @ behavior found:
     assumes \exists integer i; 0 <= i < n && *(((const char *)s) + i) == ((unsigned char)c);
     ensures found_match: *((const char *)\result) == ((unsigned char)c);
     ensures found_in_range:
       ((const char *)s) <= ((const char *)\result) < ((const char *)s) + n;
     ensures found_earliest: \forall integer i;
       ((const char *)s) <= ((const char *)s) + i < ((const char *)\result) ==>
         *(((const char *)s) + i) != ((unsigned char)c);
  
  @ complete behaviors;
  @ disjoint behaviors;
 */
void *
memchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n) {
  const char *src = (char *) s;
  c = (unsigned char) c;
  size_t i = 0;

#ifdef __GNUC__

  // Advance i until aligned on sizeof(size_t).
  /*@
    @ loop assigns i;
    @ loop invariant \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> *(src + j) != c;
    @ loop variant n - i;
   */
  for (; i < n && ((size_t)(src+i)) & ALIGN && *(src + i) != c; i++);
  //@ assert i >= n || *(src + i) == c || (((size_t)(src+i)) & ALIGN) == 0;

  // Advance i by sizeof(size_t).
  if (SS <= n && i <= (n - SS) && *(src + i) != c) {
    size_t pat = ONES * c;
    /*@
      @ loop assigns i;
      // @ loop invariant \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> *(src + j) != c;
      @ loop variant n - i;
     */
    while (i <= n - SS && !HASZERO(*((size_t *) (src + i)) ^ pat)) {
      i += SS;
    }
    //@ admit \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> *(src + j) != c;
  }

#endif

  /*@
    @ loop assigns i;
    @ loop invariant \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> *(src + j) != c;
    @ loop variant n - i;
   */
  for (; i < n && *(src + i) != c; i++);
  return (i >= n) ? 0 : ((void *) src + i);
}


This kind of code is beyond current Frama-C/WP capabilities. Basically, the main (industrial) use-cases of Frama-C/WP are generally programs with strongly constrained coding rules. Such codes are generally well-typed and use very few operations on bits. Consequently, heterogeneous casts, unions and bit operation have a poor support in Frama-C/WP.
Here are the properties that are intractable:

the link between the values read as char and read as size_t,
the fact that extracting 8 bits at some location is the extraction of a byte.

There is currently ongoing research effort to deal with the first problem, that will probably need additional R&D effort on industrial use cases to be fully scalable.
On the second aspect, to the best of my knowledge, there have been questions along years on this topic, but no industrial will to improve this feature in WP.
